# How to preg_match all three cases in the content-disposition header?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to decode the content-disposition header (from curl) to get the filename using the following regular expression:

```
<?php
$str = 'attachment;filename="unnamed.jpg";filename*=UTF-8\'\'unnamed.jpg\'';
preg_match('/^.*?filename=(["\'])([^"\']+)\1/m', $str, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

So while it matches if the filename is in single or double quotes, it fails if there are no quotes around the filename (which can happen)

```
$str = 'attachment;filename=unnamed.jpg;filename*=unnamed.jpg';
```

Right now I'm using two regular expressions (with if-else) but I just wanted to learn if it is possible to do in a single regex? Just for my own learning to master regex.

Comment: [`^.*?filename=(?(?=["\'])(["\'])[^"\']+\1|[^;]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/kPyg62/1/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will use the *branch reset* feature `(?|...|...|...)` that gives a more readable pattern and avoids to create a capture group for the quotes. In a branch-reset group, each capture groups have the same numbers for each alternative:

```
if ( preg_match('~filename=(?|"([^"]*)"|\'([^\']*)\'|([^;]*))~', $str, $match) )
    echo $match[1], PHP_EOL;
```

Whatever the alternative that succeeds, the capture is always in group 1.

Answer (score 3):

Just to put my two cents in - you could use a *conditional regex*:

```
filename=(['"])?(?(1)(.+?)\1|([^;]+))
```

---

Broken down, this says:

```
filename=   # match filename=
(['"])?     # capture " or ' into group 1, optional
(?(1)       # if group 1 was set ...
    (.+?)\1 # ... then match up to \1
    |       # else
    ([^;]+) # not a semicolon
)
```

Afterwards, you need to check if group 2 or 3 was present.
Alternatively, go for @Casimir's answer using the (often overlooked) branch reset.

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/fHaWld/1).

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use an alternation in a single regex to match either a single/double quoted filename, or a filename which is completely unquoted.  Note that one side effect of this approach is that we introduce more capture groups into the regex.  So we need a bit of extra logic to handle this.

```
<?php
    $str = 'attachment;filename=unnamed.jpg;filename*=UTF-8\'\'unnamed.jpg\'';
    $result = preg_match('/^.*?filename=(?:(?:(["\'])([^"\']+)\1)|([^"\';]+))/m',
        $str, $matches);
    print_r($matches);
    $index = count($matches) == 3 ? 2 : 3;
    if ($result) {
        echo $matches[$index];
    }
    else {
        echo "filename not found";
    }
?>
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

You could make your capturing group optional `(["\'])?` and `\1?` like:
and add a semicolon or end of the string to the end of the regex in a non capturing group which checks if there is a `;` or the end of the line `(?:;|$)`

[`^.*?filename=(["\'])?([^"\']+)\1?(?:;|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/XKouqa/1)

```
$str = 'attachment;filename=unnamed.jpg;filename*=UTF-8\'\'unnamed.jpg\'';
preg_match('/^.*?filename=(["\'])?([^"\']+)\1?(?:;|$)/m', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

[Output php](https://3v4l.org/tPK8T)

You can also use `\K` to reset the starting point of the reported match and then match until you encounter a double quote or a semicolon `[^";]+`. This will only return the filename.

[`^.*?filename="?\K[^";]+`](https://regex101.com/r/G7Gjmh/1/)

```
foreach ($strings as $string) {
    preg_match('/^.*?filename="?\K[^";]+/m', $string, $matches);
    print_r($matches);
}
```

[Output php](https://3v4l.org/UkX38)